# different trace-id for each api request

Tags: angular, azure-application-insights, open-telemetry, opentracing, distributed-tracing

My angular SPA application is calling a back end api which in turn can call multiple apis.

To see the end-to-end trace, we are using application insights sdk `"@microsoft/applicationinsights-web": "^2.5.4"` enabling **W3C** tracing mode.

The issue is that all the different api calls from the SPA are having the same **trace-id**. So in azure application insight end-to-end trace, I see too many request traces under the same browser parent.

**what I want is a different trace-id for each new api request.**

**traceparent** is like `00-1e9d1a6e585e4d35afc5af825fadaa86-f50cda29ee924950-01` where `1e9d1a6e585e4d35afc5af825fadaa86` is the trace-id.

No matter what i change in settings, it does not work as intended.

```
  this.appInsights = new ApplicationInsights({
    config: {
      instrumentationKey: settings.appInsightsConfig.instrumentationKey,
      distributedTracingMode: DistributedTracingModes.W3C,
      disableCorrelationHeaders: false,
      enableDebug: false,
      enableCorsCorrelation: true,
      enableRequestHeaderTracking: true,
      enableAutoRouteTracking: true,
      autoTrackPageVisitTime: true,
      enableAjaxErrorStatusText: true
    }
  });
```

Comment: From the documentation recommendations you're missing ```enableResponseHeaderTracking: true```. Is that intentional?

Comment: no, I really don't understand the differences even after reading documentations.

Comment: [Telemetry correlation in Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/correlation)

Comment: as i implied before, this link is not useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `distributedTracingMode: DistributedTracingModes.W3C` would enable the [W3C TraceContext based distributed tracing](https://w3c.github.io/trace-context/). In current scenario, it looks like the traceID is not getting refreshed for newer operation causing every operation to be displayed in a single transaction.

You could manually refresh the Operation ID, by calling `appInsights.properties.context.telemetryTrace.traceID = Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Telemetry.Util.generateW3CId()`.

Manually triggering a PageView event will also reset the Operation ID, but with SPA, only one page view event is generated. Therefore, I would suggest placing the setting the `traceID`  using `generateW3CId()` method in code as appropriate. For more details, refer to the following

[FAQ of transaction-diagnostics (Azure Monitor)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/transaction-diagnostics#faq)